# Assign line colors to density plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a density plot where only the lines of the single histograms are visible for more clearity/better visibility.

Here is some code for a reproducible example:

```
# create random vectors
set.seed(1)
model1 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model2 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model3 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model4 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model5 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model6 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model7 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model8 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)
model9 <- runif(n=1000, min=25, max=50)

# combine the vectors to a data frame
Tmax.df <- data.frame(model1, model2, model3, model4, model5, model6, model7, model8, model9)

# melt the data frame
Tmax.df <- melt(Tmax.df)

# plot
ggplot(Tmax.df, aes(x=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_density() +
  xlab("Daily Maximum Temperature [°C]") + ylab("Density") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(0,45), breaks= seq(0,45,5)) + scale_y_continuous(limits= c(0, 0.1)) +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.text= element_text(size=25, color= "black"), axis.title= element_text(size=25), 
        legend.text= element_text(size= 20))
```

The following plot is the result:
[image]

I would like to assign certain colors for the single lines, so that there is a contrast, making the individual lines easy to assign to their respective model data.
The colors could be these:

```
line_col <- c("black", "orange3", "orangered", "red", "gray", "skyblue4", "blue", "navyblue", "yellow")
```

Ideally, the legend should be adjusted too, so that there are no longer filled squares, but simple line symbols in the respective colors.

Anybody with a hint?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'distinct colors'. The colors you have _are_ distinct, and in fact by default are maximially spaced in terms of hue. The problem is that the more series you have, the harder it is to distinguish all of them. Nine different series with nine different colors is already a bit beyond what would be considered good practice from a data viz perspective. You could add `+ scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')` to get a different palette with better contrast.

Comment: Also, if you want lines instead of boxes in the legend, replace `geom_density()` with `stat_density(geom="line")`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I adjusted the question so that the desired colors are mentioned now.
Adding ```stat_density(geom="line")``` does change the legend, but unfortunately also the plot. Suddenly the lines go beyond the maximum of the y-axis.

Comment: Add `+scale_color_manual(values = line_col)` to your plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hacky solution creating a new guide function `custom_legend()` for the legend that displays a **line** instead of a **rectangle**.

We use `key_glyph = "path", key_grob = custom_legend` to modify `geom_density()` to replace the rectangles with lines in the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)

custom_legend <- function (data, params, size) 
{
  lwd <- min(data$size, min(size) / 4)
  lwd <- grid::unit(lwd, "mm")
  grid::segmentsGrob(0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, gp = grid::gpar(lwd = lwd, col = data$colour))
}

line_col <- c("black", "orange3", "orangered", "red", "gray", "skyblue4", "blue", "navyblue", "yellow")

ggplot(Tmax.df, aes(x = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_density(key_glyph = "path", key_grob = custom_legend) +  
  xlab("Daily Maximum Temperature [°C]") +
  ylab("Density") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 45), breaks = seq(0, 45, 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = line_col) +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 25, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 25),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]